# CycleGAN produce only black images

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I have implement a `CycleGAN` from a tutorial. After one or two epoch it only produce ***fully **BLACK images.***** No changes happen. Here is my code in GitHub .    I have not understand what is the reason. Please anyone give me any idea.

Comment: Could you please post the complete code for your model, along with a description of the hyperparameters you’ve tried? (e.g. learning rate, dropoff, decay, layer sizes,  epochs, batch size, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t clear enough. You need to “make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself”: from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, i have understood. There are lots of code. So which causes that problem, i do not know. It is not possible to post all the code.